# What does “showed why he is feared on” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Sorena Ali Madadi **showed why he is feared on** the counterattack,
>   breaking through in the middle and scoring for Princo after 35 minutes
>   to make the score 4 - 0.

What does it mean?

Comment: This could be rephrased: "Sorena Ali Madadi's counterattack showed why he is feared."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we must assume that Sorena Ali Madadi is feared, in whatever sport this is.

*Showed why he is feared* means that he proved to everyone that they *should* fear him, because he is good at the sport that he plays.

The *on* in the sentence is not really part of the phrase, but is actually just a preposition attached to *the counterattack*. A [*counterattack*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/counterattack) is an attack made to offset or reply to another attack.

Note: The other players/fans are not afraid of him in the sense that they fear for their safety, but rather they know he is a good player, and that jeopardizes their chances of winning, etc.